# How to write an awk script that catch ping's time

Tags: scripts, awk

In this line:

`Reply from 10.11.12.13 time=1035ms`

how to write an awk script which brings out just `1035`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use for example:

```
ping host | awk 'BEGIN {FS="[=]|[ ]"} {print $11}'
```

or, better to stop `ping` after  sending  one or more packets:

```
ping -c 1 host | awk 'BEGIN {FS="[=]|[ ]"} NR==2 {print $11}'
```

or

```
ping -c 5 host | awk 'BEGIN {FS="[=]|[ ]"} NR>=2&&NR<=6 {print $11}'
```

---

If you refer at this string: "Reply from 10.11.12.13 time=1035ms" and not at the output of `ping` command, you can use:

```
echo "Reply from 10.11.12.13 time=1035ms" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="[=]|ms"} {print $2}'
```

Comment: @moreroz `echo "Reply from 10.11.12.13 time=1035ms" | awk 'BEGIN {FS="[=]|ms"} {print $2}'`

Comment: @moreroz But `ping` doesn't have in the output a string something like "Reply from ..."

Comment: thanks, would you think -n is better. That you say has an output like this 123ms .whould you please change the code which its output is 123.

Comment: @moreroz Well, use `ms` as field separator. In my case, after number is a space character.

Comment: A shorter one: `awk -Ftime= 'NF>1{print $2+0}'`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the time is always reported in milliseconds:

```
$ echo "Reply from 10.11.12.13 time=1035ms" | grep -oP '\d+(?=ms)'
1035
```

Using GNU awk, print the digits after the first `=`:

```
gawk 'match($0, /=([[:digit:]]+)/, a) {print a[1]}'
```